# Coin rotation paradox

Tags: circles, puzzle

[Find the number of rotations (from our perspective) of a coin of radius $r$ around the rim of a stationary coin of radius $R$ such that the moving coin comes to its original/starting position.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_rotation_paradox)

The answer is $\frac{R}{r}+1$. The logic, as I read, is, the moving coin's center travels a distance of $2\pi{(R+r)}$ which is $\frac{R}{r}+1$ times the moving coin's circumference.

I get why the center moves $2\pi{(R+r)}$ units, but I don't understand how the argument works here, that is, why we consider the distance travelled by the center out of all things, and why we divide by the circumference of the moving coin to calculate the rotation. I can understand the argument holds but can not convince myself.

Comment: Imagine a thread wrapped around $C_r$ (coin of radius $r$), and suppose the rim of $C_R$ (coin of radius $R$) is sticky. As $C_r$ rolls, the part of the thread that is stuck to $C_R$'s rim is exactly the length of the distance traveled by the center of $C_r$ along the circumference of radius $R+r$.

Comment: There is a nice [mathologer video](https://youtu.be/oEN0o9ZGmOM?t=523) that explains it very well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Distance travelled by the center of the radius $r$ coin is $d=2\pi (R+r)$, as you see.

That means the question is equivalent to "If a coin is rolled a distance of $d=2\pi (R+r)$ on a flat surface, how many rotations does it make?"

From here, we can note the circumference of the coin is $C_r=2\pi r$, meaning every $2\pi r$ units rolled on a flat surface is 1 full rotation.

So the number of rotations is the number of $C_r$ we can fit into $d$,
$$ \frac{d}{C_r} = \frac{2\pi (R+r)}{2 \pi r} = \frac{R+r}{r} = \frac{R}{r} + 1 $$

Comment: Excellent solution. What about the distance traveled by a point on the edge of the circle. There are two points that we might be interested in. One that is tangent to both circles and one that is opposite to that point. Do these points trace out cycloids or epicycles? And can we solve the problem this way.